# How does one solve a dilemma between instinct and reason?

Tags: reason

Philosophy is often said to expound upon rational instincts that one feels behind things. But what if something happens that results in a conflict between what you find reasonable and what pulls at your instincts?

For example, suppose I have a dream in specific detail about an event and then it happens the next day. If it did, my instincts would tell me that my mind somehow “knew” the future. Yet through reason, I would still not find it justified to think this is the case since correlation does not imply causation, especially if something like this does not happen again. I also just wouldn’t be able to understand how that is even possible given the rest of my knowledge about the world.

When cases that breed uncertainty have occurred in my life, it seems that no further rational analysis can get rid of that uncertainty. Gun to my head though, if I had to pick, I pick the option that seems more rationally justified in my head, but the feeling of uncertainty does not go away. My curious nature seems to always want me to figure out the truth, atleast in a way where I am reasonably certain.

Note that when I say reasonably certain, I don’t mean absolutely certain, but rather the kind of certainty that one feels in knowing that the sun will rise tomorrow.

Are there any philosophers that talk about the dilemma between what you feel or intuit rather than reason? I know this is not always a dichotomy and one influences the other but I’m still curious to know who has talked about this.

Comment: See e.g. William James, [What is an Instinct? (1887)](https://brocku.ca/MeadProject/James/James_1887.html) as well as [The Principles of Psychology (1890)](https://psychclassics.yorku.ca/James/Principles/index.htm)